# Stop rendering layout inside the controller actions

Tags: php, codeigniter, layout

I am using the [layout](http://www.syahzul.com/blogs/item/codeigniter-layout-without-using-additional-library) method to render my template in CI framework, I add some modification to the code on the link that stop rendering the layout if the request is AJAX

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

   return;

  } else {
      //render the layout (the code from example in the link)
 }
```

The problem I face is that I am using AjaxFileUpload to upload files to server, the request type is Synchronous, and this mean rendering the layout! the response returns as jSon + HTML and that's a normal flow for the layout condition, What should I do to prevent rendering the layout if the request is synchronous when uploading file.

here is the js

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
url : url ",
secureuri :false,
fileElementId :'imageFile',
dataType : 'json',
type: "POST",

success : function (data)
{
  console.log(data);

},
error: function (request, status, error) { 

}
});
```

and here what I return from the server

```
 echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
 return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a simple solution for this pass null to you layout variable

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout = 'default';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

   public function ajax_call()
    {
        $this->layout = null;
       echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
       // you can use this but your layout should be null
       $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but it cause this warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: url"
but I fix it bu making the data type in js to jsonp

Comment: the response return as <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"> 
{"status":"error","msg":"image has uploaded successfully"}</pre> Do u have any suggestion haw can I remove the pre tag!

Comment: which method you are using echo json_encode or setting output

Comment: the same you use
 $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));

but I remove the json_encode in the line before the comments.